# Saving a string that contains both single and double quotes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object that looks like the following:

```
obj = {book: `{title: "${this.book.title}"}`}
```

`this.book.title` is a string that could contain unescaped single quote ' or double quote ".

So if the title contains a " like `This is a "book"`, then `obj` would be invalid since it would look like:

```
obj = {book: `{title: "This is a "book""}`}
```

Is there a better way than doing `this.book.title = this.book.title.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1");` to escape the quotes?

Comment: What is the desired end result?

Comment: Your code  actually creates an object with a `book` property whose value is a string (that's what backticks do).

Comment: @JordanRunning The desired result is the `obj` can be syntactically correct and I can access obj.book to retrieve a string.

Comment: You can also store base64encoded version of string in there, then decode it when you need to read it.

Comment: If you *really* want a string like that, just do `obj = {book: JSON.stringify(this.book)};`, but I'd examine why you're doing it like that. That will get you all properties on `this.book` of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't super clear, but it seems like what you want is this:

```js
this.book = { title: 'This is a "book"' };

const obj = { book: JSON.stringify({ title: this.book.title }) };

console.log(obj); // <- this is an object
console.log(obj.book); // <- this is a string
```